# Navigating with JQuery Mobile

Tags: html, url, navigation, jquery-mobile

I've had much trouble with this, I am new to JQuery.

I have the following site:

- http://www.------.com/testing.php

It is composed of 2 documents:

- view-source:www.------.com/testing.php
- view-source:www.-------.com/connection.php

The first two pages (`./testing#homepage` and `./testing#testing`) list letters and names beginning with the letter clicked respectively.

The third page is from the 2nd document and has the 'add a review' page reached by clicking a name.

In the 'add a review' page I have the following code to navigate back to the homepage:

```
<a href="http://www.-------.com/testing.php#homepage" data-icon="back">Go directly to page 1</a>
```

It for some reason displays a bunch of names which should be on testing.php#testing not
testing.php#homepage

I've tried many combinations to no avail. I also cannot get the third page to navigate back to the second page!

Any help/tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In connection.php try this

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a"> 
    <h2>'Nova Teachers</h2> 
    <h1></h1><a href="#homepage" data-icon="home">Go directly to page 1</a>
</div>
```